# How to turn anonymous user to permanent If an anonymous user confirmed his email?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to have a non-anonymous user? I want to have a passwordless email only signin, the user receives an email and confirm his email. Then I want to toggle isAnonymous to false.

My code:

```js
const { user } = await signInAnonymously(auth)
await updateEmail(user, email)
await sendEmailVerification(user)
setInterval(() => auth.currentUser.reload(), 2000)
```

[As you can see the user verified his email but still isAnonymous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tsx1.png)

**Edit**

Not possible, the user won't be able to sign in. Every time the user tries to sign in he will create a new anonymous user which when updating the user (`await updateEmail(user, email)`) will result in auth/email-already-in-use.

### **Needs Firebase to implement a true passwordless way.**

Comment: If you [sign in with an email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) the user should **not** be identified as anonymous. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have added a small section of the code.

Comment: Instead of `signInAnonymously` and then trying to fix it yourself, consider using the [sign in with an email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) option I shared above as it combines the first three API calls in your code into a single call.

Comment: Using the `signInWithEmailLink` won't work in my case. The user signs in on the app, and confirm his email on desktop or any other device.Is there any way around it? without using custom tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your authentication mechanism here.

First, you need to create a custom Endpoint to check the user's email address on the backend and in response the backend will send firebase custom token using [Firebase admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). This is a JWT token which will be used on the frontend for authenticating with firebase.

```
const uid = 'user-email';
getAuth()
    .createCustomToken(uid)
    .then((customToken) => {
        // Send token back to client
     })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
    });
```

Secondly, on the frontend your application will authenticate with firebase using the following [Firebase Client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) method.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
```

Comment: This is what I might end up doing if I didn't find good solutions.

Comment: @Shrod1987 If you implement this. please let me know 